# How can I count rows in a JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I have four tables that I want to combine with table "pro_quiz_statistic_ref" using JOIN. All tables are joining just fine except one table and that's "pro_quiz_stastic".

The table "pro_quiz_statistic_ref" are holding all quiz that users has participated in.

In pro_quiz_statistic there is records with 10 answers from each quiz and of course there is statistic_ref_id to identify which quiz it belongs to. 
I want to make a count on the column "correct_count" in table "pro_quiz_statistic" with the same statistic_ref_id.

I have this query:

```
$results_quiz = $pdo->query("SELECT 
    sr.statistic_ref_id, 
    sr.quiz_id, 
    sr.user_id, 
    sr.total_time, 
    qm.name AS q_name, 
    qm.category_id,
    qm.subcategory_id,
    sc.sub_category_id,
    sc.sub_category_name AS quiz_type,
    pl.time,
    pl.points,
    qs.correct_count AS count_correct 
    FROM pro_quiz_statistic_ref AS sr 
    JOIN pro_quiz_master qm ON qm.id = sr.quiz_id 
    JOIN pro_quiz_subcategory sc ON sc.sub_category_id = qm.subcategory_id
    JOIN user_points_log pl ON pl.quiz_id = sr.quiz_id AND pl.user_id = '$get_id'
    JOIN pro_quiz_statistic qs ON qs.statistic_ref_id = sr.statistic_ref_id
    WHERE sr.user_id = '$get_id' ORDER BY qm.name ASC");
```

With code above it prints out all quiz that user has participated in * 10 answers listed in "pro_quiz_statistic"

I have tried to write it like

```
COUNT(qs.correct_count) AS count_correct
```

but then it only print out one row.
BTW: It's also filtered by user_id.

The reason I want to use JOIN is because there is more

Can someone help me with this?

Best Regards

Kenneth

-------- UPDATED ---------

I ended up with this which is working just fine:

```
$results_quiz = $pdo->query("SELECT 
    sr.statistic_ref_id, 
    sr.quiz_id, 
    sr.user_id, 
    sr.total_time, 
    qm.name AS q_name, 
    qm.category_id,
    qm.subcategory_id,
    sc.sub_category_id,
    sc.sub_category_name AS quiz_type,
    pl.time,
    pl.points,
    COUNT(qs.correct_count) AS count_correct 
    FROM pro_quiz_statistic_ref AS sr 
    JOIN pro_quiz_master qm ON qm.id = sr.quiz_id 
    JOIN pro_quiz_subcategory sc ON sc.sub_category_id = qm.subcategory_id
    JOIN user_points_log pl ON pl.quiz_id = sr.quiz_id AND pl.user_id = '$get_id'
    JOIN pro_quiz_statistic qs ON qs.statistic_ref_id = sr.statistic_ref_id
    WHERE 
    sr.user_id = '$get_id' AND 
    qs.correct_count = '1'
    GROUP BY     
    sr.statistic_ref_id,
    qs.correct_count
  ORDER BY qm.name ASC");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an aggregation function like count(..) you should use a group by statement

```
  $results_quiz = $pdo->query("SELECT 
      sr.statistic_ref_id, 
      sr.quiz_id, 
      sr.user_id, 
      sr.total_time, 
      qm.name AS q_name, 
      qm.category_id,
      qm.subcategory_id,
      sc.sub_category_id,
      sc.sub_category_name AS quiz_type,
      pl.time,
      pl.points,
      count(qs.correct_count )AS count_correct 
      FROM pro_quiz_statistic_ref AS sr 
      JOIN pro_quiz_master qm ON qm.id = sr.quiz_id 
      JOIN pro_quiz_subcategory sc ON sc.sub_category_id = qm.subcategory_id
      JOIN user_points_log pl ON pl.quiz_id = sr.quiz_id AND pl.user_id = '$get_id'
      JOIN pro_quiz_statistic qs ON qs.statistic_ref_id = sr.statistic_ref_id
      WHERE sr.user_id = '$get_id'
      GROUP BY     
        sr.statistic_ref_id, 
        sr.quiz_id, 
        sr.user_id, 
        sr.total_time, 
        qm.name, 
        qm.category_id,
        qm.subcategory_id,
        sc.sub_category_id,
        sc.sub_category_name AS quiz_type,
        pl.time,
        pl.point
      ORDER BY qm.name ASC");
```

Comment: That's done.. I have posted another issue I have with count which are related to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656159/make-a-count-on-join-tables