# Make a COUNT on JOIN tables

Tags: mysql

I have a query which I want to COUNT the rows. The problem is when I try to count the exact same query it's printing 9 but when I run the query and print the rows it's only 5 (as it should be)

Here is the query that works and show the 5 rows:

```
$results_quiz = $pdo->query("SELECT 
    sr.statistic_ref_id, 
    sr.quiz_id, 
    sr.user_id, 
    sr.total_time, 
    qm.name AS q_name, 
    qm.category_id,
    qm.subcategory_id,
    sc.sub_category_id,
    sc.sub_category_name AS quiz_type,
    pl.time,
    pl.points,
    COUNT(qs.correct_count) AS count_correct 
    FROM pro_quiz_statistic_ref AS sr 
    JOIN pro_quiz_master qm ON qm.id = sr.quiz_id 
    JOIN pro_quiz_subcategory sc ON sc.sub_category_id = qm.subcategory_id
    JOIN user_points_log pl ON pl.quiz_id = sr.quiz_id AND pl.user_id = '$get_id'
    JOIN pro_quiz_statistic qs ON qs.statistic_ref_id = sr.statistic_ref_id
    WHERE 
    sr.user_id = '$get_id' AND 
    qs.correct_count = '1'
    GROUP BY     
    sr.statistic_ref_id,
    qs.correct_count
  ORDER BY qm.name ASC");
```

The above code works like it should but when I use this:

```
$count_results_quiz = $pdo->query("SELECT COUNT('
    sr.statistic_ref_id, 
    sr.quiz_id, 
    sr.user_id, 
    sr.total_time, 
    qm.name AS q_name, 
    qm.category_id,
    qm.subcategory_id,
    sc.sub_category_id,
    sc.sub_category_name AS quiz_type,
    pl.time,
    pl.points,
    COUNT(qs.correct_count) AS count_correct')
    FROM pro_quiz_statistic_ref AS sr 
    JOIN pro_quiz_master qm ON qm.id = sr.quiz_id 
    JOIN pro_quiz_subcategory sc ON sc.sub_category_id = qm.subcategory_id
    JOIN user_points_log pl ON pl.quiz_id = sr.quiz_id AND pl.user_id = '$get_id'
    JOIN pro_quiz_statistic qs ON qs.statistic_ref_id = sr.statistic_ref_id
    WHERE 
    sr.user_id = '$get_id' AND 
    qs.correct_count = '1'
    GROUP BY     
    sr.statistic_ref_id,
    qs.correct_count
  ORDER BY qm.name ASC")->fetchColumn();
```

it's printing "9". Anyone knows why?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: because there are 9 rows that the `sr.user_id = '$get_id' AND 
    qs.correct_count = '1` ` for them is true

Comment: But how come it's not showing 9 rows when I run the query without the count? And when I remove "AND qs.correct_count = '1' " it's still printing 9 although there is 10 rows in the table bound on that user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution by splitting the tables into two queries/tables. One of them showing more than 0 (at least 1) correct answer and the other one showing 0 correct answers. This way it also fits better to my needs.